# Почему плохо перебирать файлы/папки через ls? (Iterating over ls output is fragile. Use globs.)

Tags: bash, shell, инспекция-кода, zsh

Есть код, который должен работать в bash и zsh. Фрагмент кода перечисляет все директории, сортируя их по времени последнего изменения. Эту задачу он решает вполне успешно. Перечисляемые директории генерятся тем же кодом и содержат только символы `a-zA-Z0-9-_`, никаких пробелов.

mcve.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for i in $(ls -dt1 ./*/);
do
    echo "${i}";
done
```

Использую shellcheck:

```
shellcheck mcve.sh
```

Получаю следующий результат:

```
In mcve.sh line 2:
    for i in $(ls -dt1 ./*/);
             ^-- SC2045: Iterating over ls output is fragile. Use globs.
```

В чём "хрупкость" этого метода? Как я могу его улучшить?

Очевидный вариант "использовать глобы" не подходит, т.к. нужна сортировка по времени.

Comment: Это уже было в Симпсонах :-) То есть подробный ответ здесь: http://stackoverflow.com/a/938052/5703199

Comment: @PinkTux спасибо, прочитал )

Comment: Если попросту, то, например, имя файла  `a b` for разобьет на 2 -- `a` и `b` (да, @alexander barakin уже подробно ответил, и дал рекомендации лучше, чем в принятом ответе)

Comment: Где-то я видел большой развёрнутый ответ на ту тему.

Comment: @Qwertiy у нас или на английском? Вон выше PinkTux ссылку оставил.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, нашёл: https://habrahabr.ru/post/47706/ - прям под первым номером.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема в том, что `ls` предназначена в первую очередь для отображения списка файлов в понятном пользователю формате. Это включает всякие метки и прочие обозначения, которые `ls` прибавляет к наименованиям файлов.

`ls -1` не добавляет меток, но это не избавляет от «расцвечивания». Кроме того, работа `ls` может варьироваться от настроек окружения и операционной системы, что переводит её из разряда «универсальное решение» в разряд «может работать».

Так же не стоит забывать, что совсем нередко пользователи при помощи алиаса задают дефолтные настройки для `ls`.

Для того, чтобы получить некий список файлов и передать его в качестве параметров какой-то другой команде, обычно используют `find`. Например, чтобы получить список поддиректорию в текущей директории, отсортированный по `mtime`, можно сделать как-нибудь так:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf “%C@ %p\n" | sort | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: `ls -1` не прибавляет никаких меток и обозначений. А вы можете привести пример имени директории, на котором "хрупкий" ls действительно сломается?

Comment: Но при отсутствии меток, это не избавляет от «расцвечивания». Кроме того, работа `ls` может варьироваться от настроек окружения и операционной системы, что переводит её из разряда «универсальное решение» в разряд «может работать».

Comment: Так же не стоит забывать, что совсем нередко пользователи при помощи алиаса задают дефолтные настройки для `ls`.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, [Pin Tux указал ссылку](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/578748/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%85%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-ls-iterating-over-ls-output-is-fragi#comment767133_578748), в которой есть [ссылка на статью, отвечающую на ваш вопрос о "хрупкости"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) ;)

Answer (score 4):

под «хрупкостью», вероятно, подразумевалась обработка спец-символов, которые могут встретиться в именах файлов/каталогов. например, пробел:

```
$ mkdir "1 2" 3
$ for i in $(ls); do echo "${i}"; done
1
2
3
```

в то время как использование *glob* даст корректный результат:

```
$ for i in *; do echo "${i}"; done
1 2
3
```

данной проблемы можно избежать, если заключить вложенную команду в кавычки:

```
$ for i in "$(ls)"; do echo "${i}"; done
1 2
3
```