# гибкий поиск вхождения слова через grep

Tags: linux, grep

Нужно найти вхождение слова или фразы, в текстовых файлах по проекту.
Папок очень много. Делаю таким образом:
`grep -rwi "phrase" /path-to/project`
Ищет все вхождения. Но, допустим я хочу исключить из поиска 2-3 папки внутри проекта, в которых искать не нужно, как это сделать без перебора папок вручную?

Answer (score 6):

Исключите директории через параметр `--exclude-dir=`. В качестве значения - шаблон имени (имён) который требуется исключить.

P. S. Кстати, вам так же может пригодиться аналогичный вопрос на "материнском" ресурсе - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565471/how-can-i-exclude-directories-from-grep-r. Он содержит не мало примеров, а так же варианты с использованием `find`.

Answer (score 2):

```bsh
 ls -la **/* | grep '^d' | grep -vi "down*" | grep -wi "phrase"
```

теперь подробнее:

`ls -la **/*` - выдает все файлы от текущей директории и субдиректории

`| grep '^d'` - из этого списка выбирает папки только

`| grep -vi "down*"` - из этого выбирает те папки, которые не начинаются с `down*`

`| grep -rwi "phrase"` - это уже ваш поиск

Comment: всю конструкцию `ls -la **/* | grep '^d' | grep -vi "down*"` можно смело заменить на `:` — она не оказывает никакого влияния на последнюю часть конвейера — `grep -rwi "phrase"`

Comment: т.е., фактически, ничем не отличается от команды, приведённой в вопросе. и, соответственно, никак не отвечает на сам вопрос.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin правы, ключ `r` был лишний тут. исправил, спасибо.

Comment: а что в этом случае ищется-то? на выходе после `ls -la **/* | grep '^d' | grep -vi "down*"` получается просто набор «мусора», выданного программой `ls`.

Comment: А теперь (без -r) ищете в **именах** файлов (а в вопросе просят в содержимом)

Comment: @avp, вообще-то в списке не будет никаких файлов. там будут записи вида `drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Jul 20  2013 .`, из которых весьма сложно извлечь что-либо полезное для ответа на вопрос.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, согласен. (тогда в именах оглавлений)

Comment: Парсить вывод ls - обычно плохая идея. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/578772/181472