# Удаление файлов и папок кроме некоторых

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat

Подскажите, как удалить файлы и папки кроме одной? В Ubuntu 16.04.
Сама папка находится по такому пути `/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/`.

Делаю скрипт, который сам деплоит (распаковывает) проект для tomcat'а из архива.
Сам скрипт `.sh` находится в корне.

Я попробовал сделать так:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/
sudo ls | grep -v 'test' | xargs rm -rf
sudo rm /var/lib/tomcat8/logs/catalina.out
sleep 100
cd ..
sudo unzip -qq Site.war -d /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/
sudo chown -R tomcat8:tomcat8 /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT
sudo service tomcat8 restart
#sudo rm /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/Site.war
```

Но так получилось, что у меня снеслась вся система - пришлось переустанавливать.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно это сделать?

Comment: `sleep 100` зачем?

Comment: @NickVolynkin наверно для задержки. нашел это в инете.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Рассмотрим одну из строчек вашего скрипта. Тут содержится уязвимость, вероятно, из-за этого и сломалась система.

> ```
> sudo ls | grep -v 'test' | xargs rm -rf
> ```

Вообще говоря, [разбирать вывод утилиты **ls** — очень плохая идея](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/578748). То, что показывает **ls**, предназначено в первую очередь для чтения человеком.

Лучшим подходом будет использование утилиты **find** в сочетании с **xargs** примерно таким образом

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -not -name test -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf --
```

- `-maxdepth 1` ограничивает область поиска текущим каталогом (так сделано для упрощения последующего условия)
- `-not -name test` — а это по сути само условие поиска (файлы, чьё имя не *test*)

  Если файлов, которые хотим сохранить, несколько, их можно перечислять, добавляя дополнительные предикаты `-name`.
- `-print0` заставляет **find** печатать имена файла, разделяя их нулевым байтом, чтобы **xargs** в последствии правильно бы их считала (для этого используется флаг `-0`)

---

Мне ещё импонирует вот такой «башизм» для указания всех файлов в текущем каталоге кроме заданного. Активируется он с помощью встроенной команды **shopt**, которая меняет параметры работы текущей оболочки.

```
shopt -s extglob dotglob
rm -rf -- !(test)
```

Опция **extglob** включает такой расширенный синтаксис файловой подстановки, **dotglob** нужна, чтобы также подставлялись и скрытые файлы.

Несколько файлов, которые нужно уберечь от удаления, перечисляются в круглых скобках с разделителями — вертикальными палочками `|`.

---

И да, мне не очень нравится, что у вас **sudo** суть ли не в каждой строчке. Думаю, вам стоит избавиться от этого, но сам скрипт запускать, дав ему права суперпользователя.

Comment: Скрипт удаления нашел в инете.

Спасибо. Учту ваши замечания. 
Я так понимаю можно или первым способом или вторым?

Comment: Да, какой вам больше нравится. Кажется, они равнозначны.

Comment: Ещё такой вопрос. мне это нужно вызывать находясь в нужной мне папке? тобишь я перешел в каталог по команде `cd` и потом вызываю команду на удаление?

Comment: Не обязательно. Это как вам удобнее. Главное правильно указать относительный путь.

Comment: Можете пример привести. Я не совсем в  этом разбираюсь, а сносить ещё раз систему как-то не хочется.

Спасибо.

Comment: Я бы вообще использовал только абсолютные пути. https://paste.ubuntu.com/24182301/ Но вам нужно принять во внимание, что я ещё не сталкивался с tomcat, и, возможно, есть другое, более красивое решение

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: Вы тут ввели в повествование `shopt`, но не рассказали, что это. Неопытному читателю непонятно будет. Я вот вроде бы догадался, что эта программа меняет правила раскрытия глобов в баше, но всё равно не уверен.

Comment: `Тут содержится уязвимость` – тоже не совсем понятно. Корни уязвимости явно растут из использования `ls`, но что же конкретно произошло, от чего система пострадала? Рекурсивный перебор «наверх»?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, давайте представим, что у нас в текущем каталоге есть файл с именем `qwe ..` (с пробелом перед точками). Тогда команда из вопроса попытается удалить предыдущий каталог. Если предположить, что для ls заведён псевдоним `ls -p` и имеется каталог, имя которого завершается пробелом, получим `rm -rf /` в чистом виде. Возможно есть ещё какие варианты, сходу придумать не могу.

Comment: @mymedia ого, отличные примеры. )

Comment: К моему огорчению, раскрытие вида `!(test)` не работает из коробки по умолчанию, поэтому пришлось включить такое поведение с помощью встроенной команды для изменеия параметров оболочки.

Comment: @mymedia предлагаю прямо в ответе и написать, что "`shopt` – это встроенная команда...". А то я-то понял из комментариев, но мало кто их читает. А в ответе остался непонятный момент.