# Как удалить все папки/файлы кроме определённых?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, ubuntu, удаление

Я не знаю в какую сторону копать, поэтому я тут.

Есть папка `messages`, в которой хранится локализация. Нужно удалить в ней все папки рекурсивно, кроме папки с именами `ru`/`ru-RU`.  Все папки в таком формате: либо две буквы `us`/`ru`/`hr`, либо стандартно четыре `ru-RU`/`en-US` и т.д.

Или папка `i18n`, в которой хранится локализация. Нужно удалить в ней все файлы, кроме файлов с именами `ru.js`/`ru-RU.js`. Все файлы в таком формате: либо две буквы `us.js`/`ru.js`/`hr.js`, либо стандартно четыре `ru-RU.js`/`en-US.js` и т.д.

---

Про удаление `sudo rm -rf PATH_TO_FOLDER` и `sudo rm -rf PATH_TO_FOLDER/*` знаю. Но вот как удалить все кроме указанных - не знаю.

Как это сделать?

P.S. На каком уровне вложенности находятся те самыe папки messages и i18n, в которых находятся папки/файлы для удаления - я не знаю. А удалять все папки мне не нужно. Нужно удалять только в папках локализаций (их может быть несколько под некоторые плагины)

---

Пример структуры

```
- 1
  - messages
    - ru
    - en
    - hr
- 2
  - src
    - plug
      - messages
        - ru
        - en
        - ja
        - ku
- 3
  - table-builder
    - src
      - i18n
        - en.js
        - hr.js
        - la.js
        - ru.js
- 4
  - drop-down
    - src
      - assets
        - js
          - i18n
            - en.js
            - gb.js
            - ru-RU.js
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Удаление файлов и папок кроме некоторых](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/639519/%d0%a3%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%85)

Comment: @Spatz не получится дубль. На каком уровне вложенности находятся те самыe папки messages и i18n, в которых находятся папки/файлы для удаления - я не знаю. А удалять все папки мне не нужно. Нужно удалять только в папках локализаций (их может быть несколько под некоторые плагины). Добавил это в вопрос

Answer (score 4, accepted):

например, можно воспользоваться программой *find*.

демонстрация:

```
$ mkdir -p 1/messages/{ru,en,hr} 2/src/plug/messages/{ru,en,ja,ku} 3/table/src/i18n/{en,hr,la,ru}.js 4/drop/src/assets/js/i18n/{en,gb,ru-RU}.js
$ tree
.
├── 1
│   └── messages
│       ├── en
│       ├── hr
│       └── ru
├── 2
│   └── src
│       └── plug
│           └── messages
│               ├── en
│               ├── ja
│               ├── ku
│               └── ru
├── 3
│   └── table
│       └── src
│           └── i18n
│               ├── en.js
│               ├── hr.js
│               ├── la.js
│               └── ru.js
└── 4
    └── drop
        └── src
            └── assets
                └── js
                    └── i18n
                        ├── en.js
                        ├── gb.js
                        └── ru-RU.js

30 directories, 0 files
```

каталоги, которые надо оставить:

```
$ find -type d -name ru\*
./3/table/src/i18n/ru.js
./1/messages/ru
./2/src/plug/messages/ru
./4/drop/src/assets/js/i18n/ru-RU.js
```

логическое отрицание:

```
$ find -type d \! -name ru\*
.
./3
./3/table
./3/table/src
./3/table/src/i18n
./3/table/src/i18n/en.js
./3/table/src/i18n/la.js
./3/table/src/i18n/hr.js
./1
./1/messages
./1/messages/hr
./1/messages/en
./2
./2/src
./2/src/plug
./2/src/plug/messages
./2/src/plug/messages/en
./2/src/plug/messages/ja
./2/src/plug/messages/ku
./4
./4/drop
./4/drop/src
./4/drop/src/assets
./4/drop/src/assets/js
./4/drop/src/assets/js/i18n
./4/drop/src/assets/js/i18n/en.js
./4/drop/src/assets/js/i18n/gb.js
```

чтобы удалять, лучше добавить опцию `-depth`, которая выдаст список «от самого длинного пути к самому короткому»:

```
$ find -depth -type d \! -name ru\*
./3/table/src/i18n/en.js
./3/table/src/i18n/la.js
./3/table/src/i18n/hr.js
./3/table/src/i18n
./3/table/src
./3/table
./3
./1/messages/hr
./1/messages/en
./1/messages
./1
./2/src/plug/messages/en
./2/src/plug/messages/ja
./2/src/plug/messages/ku
./2/src/plug/messages
./2/src/plug
./2/src
./2
./4/drop/src/assets/js/i18n/en.js
./4/drop/src/assets/js/i18n/gb.js
./4/drop/src/assets/js/i18n
./4/drop/src/assets/js
./4/drop/src/assets
./4/drop/src
./4/drop
./4
.
```

теперь удалим их, добавив опцию `-delete` (на ошибки про непустой каталог не обращаем внимание):

```
$ find -depth -type d \! -name ru\* -delete
find: cannot delete ‘./1/messages’: Directory not empty
...
```

что осталось:

```
$ tree
.
├── 1
│   └── messages
│       └── ru
├── 2
│   └── src
│       └── plug
│           └── messages
│               └── ru
├── 3
│   └── table
│       └── src
│           └── i18n
│               └── ru.js
└── 4
    └── drop
        └── src
            └── assets
                └── js
                    └── i18n
                        └── ru-RU.js

20 directories, 0 files
```

p.s. разумеется, программе *find* можно указать лишь нужные каталоги для поиска:

```
$ find каталог1 каталог2 прочие опции и параметраы
```

Comment: Спасибо! Всё нашёл, всёудалил что нужно!